# jQuery DataTable not displaying Show entries, Search and does not sort until the page is refreshed

Tags: datatable, datatables

jQuery DataTable not displaying Show entries, Search and does not sort until I refresh the page after I refresh the page it works.
 Actualy I am using it in laravel vuejs

I searched a lot but I did not find anything on the web

Thank you in advance

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
         <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer"
                role="grid"  aria-describedby="datatable_info">  <thead>
                                            <tr role="row">
                                                <th
                                                    class="sorting_asc"
                                                    tabindex="0"
                                                    aria-controls="datatable"
                                                    rowspan="1"
                                                    colspan="1"
                                                    aria-sort="ascending"
                                                    aria-label="نام: activate to sort column descending"
                                                    style="width: 140px;"
                                                >
                                                    نام
                                                </th>
                                                <th
                                                    class="sorting"
                                                    tabindex="0"
                                                    aria-controls="datatable"
                                                    rowspan="1"
                                                    colspan="1"
                                                    aria-label="جایگاه: activate to sort column ascending"
                                                    style="width: 234px;"
                                                >
                                                    جایگاه
                                                </th>                                                    
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>

                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr role="row" class="odd">
                                                <td class="sorting_1">
                                                    Airi Satou
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Accountant</td>                                                   
                                            </tr>
                                            <td class="sorting_1">
                                                    Airi Satou
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Accountant</td>                                                   
                                            </tr>                                    
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Below is the router links I implemented it in the layout.blade.php file

```
  <!-- sidebar menu -->
                    <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
                        <div class="menu_section">
                            <ul class="nav side-menu">
                                <li><a ><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <router-link to="/dashboard" class="nav-link" onclick="activeFunc();" style="color:white" >کورپاڼه </router-link> </a></li>
                                <li><a><i class="fa fa-bandcamp"></i> ثابت شتمني <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                        <li> <router-link to="/FixedAsset" class="nav-link" onclick="activeFunc();" > د شتمنیو لست  </router-link></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /sidebar menu -->
function activeFunc(){
            $("li").removeClass("active current-page");
              var currentSelectedli = $("a.router-link-exact-active").parent('li');
              currentSelectedli.addClass("current-page");
              currentSelectedli.siblings().removeClass("active current-page");
             var parentLI =currentSelectedli.parent("ul").parent("li");
             if(parentLI.length!=0){
                 parentLI.addClass("active");

             }
         }
```

any kind of help will be highly appreciated

Comment: are you using router-link ?

Comment: yes I do I will update my question check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if it worked please let me know this code  `$("#datatable").DataTable({ retrieve: true,});`
 will re initialize your datatable

```
function activeFunc(){
            $("li").removeClass("active current-page");
              var currentSelectedli = $("a.router-link-exact-active").parent('li');
              currentSelectedli.addClass("current-page");
              currentSelectedli.siblings().removeClass("active current-page");
             var parentLI =currentSelectedli.parent("ul").parent("li");
             if(parentLI.length!=0){
                 parentLI.addClass("active");
                  $("#datatable").DataTable({ retrieve: true,});
             }
         }
```